# How to make quality gate pass, although new plugins are added?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube6.3

I added two plugins to SonarQube version 6.3.0.19869 (css and web). Now all my projects fail on their quality gate.

How can I get it to pass for the first time? I can't fix all old errors now. I want to fix only new issues.

Comment: Do you use version control system? If so: which one and did you mention it in your SonarQube configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `http://yourserver:port/issues` and try to filter out exactly those issues, that you do not want to handle for the moment (probably using the "Language" or "Creation Date" filters are a good start).

Then do a "Bulk Change" (link on top of the page) to get all of these issues out of your project's quality gate.

Depending on your quality gate, this might mean to change the status of the issues from "open" to "confirmed", change their severity, or similar.

Since this approach really depends on the quality gate configuration, it does not work in all cases.

Comment: I used this approach. I bulk changed all the issues to code smell which does not fail my quality gate

Answer (score 2):

Version 6.3 included functionality to backdate new issues raised on old code by rules that are newly added to your previously applied profile.

However, that functionality still misses some cases ([SONAR-8737](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-8737)), and yours appears to be one of them.

Comment: This didn't help. Once I copied the rules back and analyzed again, the gate failed with the new new css and web rules

Comment: Did it re-open the previously-closed issues or create new ones?

Comment: They were recognized as new issues

Comment: And what is the 'blame' date on the line one of these 'new' issues is raised on?

Comment: The date I re ran the analyze (after I copied the rules back into the default profile)

Comment: Sorry, don't know what to tell you then.